# Getting error: package org.apache.hadoop.conf does not exist while Running Hadoop examples

Tags: hadoop, classpath

I have added `hadoop jars` to the classpath using export `CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:/~Downloads/hadoop-1.0.4/*.jar` but still I am getting package not found error.

I am using `Java 1.7.0_17`.

Anyone know how to set classpath for `hadoop jars` correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It's not `CLASSPATH` that you want to set them to but rather `HADOOP_CLASSPATH`. I like to use the following to add all the jar dependencies from my current and `lib` directories:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:`echo *.jar`:`echo lib/*.jar | sed 's/ /:/g'`
```

Bear in mind that if you are starting a job through `hadoop jar` you'll need to also pass it the jars through use of `-libjars`. I like to use:

```
hadoop jar <jar> <class> -libjars `echo ./lib/*.jar | sed 's/ /,/g'` [args...]
```

**NOTE:** The `sed` commands require a different delimiter character; the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` is `:` separated and the `-libjars` need to be `,` separated.